# Increasing the font size of a button

Tags: css, jsp, user-interface, struts, struts-1

I have an application made in struts 1.2 and it will be accessed by Desktop browser as well as Android browser. The layout of the DEsktop browser is fine but having problems with the layout in Android browser. Somehow I managed to do the UI look and feel changes but stuck with the button font.

Below is the code I wrote for the button:

```
<html:submit property="action" value="Login" style="width: 150px;height: 80px;"></html:submit>
```

The button appearence is fine but the font of the button i.e. `Login` is very small. I tried adding the `font: 100px;` in the `style` attribute but it did not worked.

Any suggestions on how to increase the `font` size of the submit button text?

Please let me know about this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`font` css attribute isn't what you want.. Use `font-size: 100px` instead.

In fact with `font` you can specify multiple font related attributes. [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp)

Comment: hitting Ctrl+Space in Eclipse IDE, it came as `font` also, hence got confused. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually [font](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp) exists but it isn't what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The [`font` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font) value must be either a single keyword indicating a system font or contain at least font size and font family, as in `font: 100% Calibri`. If you wish to set the font size only, do not use the `font` shorthand but the specific property `font-size`, e.g. `font-size: 30px`.